# What is an instance and how do I convert this to $

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hosting, web-hosting

You'll have to excuse my ignorance on this one...but honestly, I've had a hard time finding clarity on this. That being said, I'm looking for a non technical answer...something in layman's terms!

Anyways, I've been playing around building a web app (first time obviously) and I'm getting to the point where I've started looking into hosting services. A quick google search and a few blogs later, I thought AWS would be a good place to start, since they give a free-year trial. I don't care about speedy upstarts or other hosting serves, so save your key strokes on offering other services.

My question is based on the fact that AWS charges "[Linux Usage per hour](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)" and they also use this term "instance". Yeah...an "instance" is an "object", which is also above my head (probably the real source of the problem), but that was the extent I was able to learn via a google search. That being said, I don't know how to translate the cost into a ball park cost. Yes, I can probably use the trial to help monitor predictable costs, but I don't want to go through the effort of learning one hosting companies system just to find out it's not going to work in the end.

OK...so hopefully by now you see where I'm coming from. What is an "instance" and how do I use the "[Linux Usage per hour](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)" to estimate cost? Is an instance a server? For example if I start NGINX is that in instance? Is it just one instance running NGINX or does every VPN represent an instance? If I have 100 people calling the server at once, can they fit on one instance? If I start another server say, Apache or Node, does that become another instance? If I connect to a database, is that an instance? Do instances start as needed? Yes, I know, that's more than one question...I'm just trying to express my confusion.

If I'm suppose to choose a pricing model from this list, "[Linux Usage per hour](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/)", I need to know what them mean by "Linux Usage". If it's based on an "instance", I need to know what that is. So please, in layman's terms, help clear this up. Maybe some examples or analogies, but no deep technical stuff.

---

This is more a side note, but I was reading this [article](http://www.datalink.com/Datalink-Blog/August-2015/Is-Public-Cloud-Really-Cheaper-It-Depends) and it said

> For a client needing to run 800 virtual instances, the annual cost of
>   a private cloud came to below $400,000 vs. somewhere between $800,000
>   and $1.2 million for public cloud services.

Considering I don't know what an instance is, that kinda made me a bit nervous...WAAAAAAyyyyyy outta my price range! Yes, it's obviously a big company, but can you imagine "hitting the lottery" with an app everyone loves then before you know it, AWS hits you with a bill of $1,000,000. Or even worse, your security sucks and someone spawns millions of these "instances"...help alive my paranoia!!

Comment: in layman's terms, instance is a server

Comment: You can absolutely get burned on the billing aspect of AWS if you don't know what you are doing, and it looks like you are currently struggling with the most basic of AWS terminology. You either need to dedicate a lot of time to learn AWS, or hire or partner with someone that knows it. Otherwise I would suggest going with a simpler hosting provider like Digital Ocean.

Comment: Thanks @Mark B for giving me the heads up. That's kind of the impression I got and the reason for me asking. The freedom of AWS sounds great, but if you have to pay a price for it (either time or $, do to careless configurations), then I might as well pay $ to another host service to get it right the first time. In the end, even though AWS might be cheaper in rate, the final cost is probably more comparable after all said and done (time and $ to get it right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, an instance is a virtual machine, which looks very much like a server.  As such it's running an operating system - e.g. linux - which is capable of running many programs (aka 'processes' or sometimes, 'services') at the same time.

To go through your questions (some of the explanations below are not *technically* accurate, but are hopefully more explanatory for it - if anything is obvious or already known, apologies - trying not to assume any knowledge)

> An instance is an object

This definition is coming up in your searches because 'instance' has many definitions in different situations.  If you see the definition of 'instance' as an object, it's from the topic of object oriented programming languages - you define a class in your code (kind of like a 'template'), and then create instances of the class - kind of like real copies of the template.

Amazon borrowed the term to be analogous - because in the 'cloud' world, you can create an AMI (Amazon Machine Image - the template) and then create lots of instances that are copies or clones of that template.

> Is an instance a server?

In terms of what you can do with it, yes, it's a server.

(*Technically* it's a virtual server - Amazon runs multiple virtual servers on each physical server.)

> how do I use the "Linux Usage per hour" to estimate cost?

Estimate how long you will have your instance running for in hours per month, multiply it by cost per hour and you will have your estimated cost per instance per month.

e.g. - one instance always turned on would be - 24 hrs * 31 days = 744 hours.  At $0.013/hr (for a t2.micro) that would be 744 * $0.013 = $9.672/mth.

(And that's the reason the free tier gives you 750 hours of instance time per month.)

Instances come in different [types and sizes](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) and each size costs a different amount.  If you are not sure what size you need, I'd start with the smallest until you discover you need more - which would be when your program starts running too slowly.

> For example if I start NGINX is that in instance?

Nginx is a program that runs as a daemon in linux terms - a program that runs in the background so it's always on.  It will be one of the many programs running on the server (aka the instance)

> If I have 100 people calling the server at once, can they fit on one instance?

It depends - on how big your instance is, and how efficient the program is that is responding to their requests.  If you are just getting started learning to program websites, I wouldn't worry about handling 100 people issuing requests to the server all at once just yet - walk before you run :) (also, even when there are 100 people visiting your website, the odds that all of them issue a request at exactly the same time is low - usually they load a page and read it - while they're reading it, some of the other people are loading other pages, and it all spreads out so you might only have ~10 page requests actively being processed by your server at the same time.)

However, if you have 2,000 people on your site at the same time, you might be processing 200 page requests at once, so by then you do need to have put some thought into performance and scalability.

(Note: these numbers are arbitrary and depend entirely on the type of site and it's traffic patterns.)

Generally, most websites pick a mid-level instance size, and then to handle more requests they 'scale out' - create lots of copies of that instance, and allow each instance to handle a portion of the traffic.

> If I start another server say, Apache or Node, does that become another instance

The language to use here would be 'start another service say, Apache or Node' - they are other programs, and your instance will be perfectly fine running nginx, apache and node all at the same time.  Although each will consume some of the resources (e.g. memory and cpu) and the more activity they are doing, the faster you will run out of resources and need to get a bigger instance size

So - no, they don't automatically become another instance.  The language is confusing because sometimes people don't distinguish between the 'server' (aka the instance) and the service (aka the program) and will say the 'apache server' and the 'apache service' interchangably.

> If I connect to a database, is that an instance?

Your instance, as a fully capable server, could run a database service on it at the same time as the other services - e.g. you could install and run mysql on your instance.

There is another option, though - if you use the AWS RDS product, then you will be starting an RDS instance.  An RDS instance is different from an EC2 instance (what we've been talking about so far) in that RDS instances are specialised to just run the database service and nothing else, but EC2 instances are general servers that you can do pretty much anything on.

It's usually recommended to use RDS, but if you are trying to save money and aren't serving many users, there's nothing particularly wrong with installing mysql on your instance yourself (especially while you're learning how it works) and then moving your data to an RDS instance when you want to support more load or traffic.

> Do instances start as needed?

Not by default, no - you have to manually start and stop them.

However, there are options other than manually starting and stopping.  Amazon provides a lot of APIs, so you could write a program that would connect to the API and automatically start and stop your instance(s) based on rules you build into your program..

Also, Amazon offers a product called "AutoScalingGroups" which allows you to have a related group of instances and for Amazon to automatically start and stop them according to rules that you configure into that product.  These rules can be 'scheduled actions' - start/stop at certain times of day - or they can be reactive - e.g. when the average CPU usage is > 50% for more than 5 minutes, start another instance.

> This is more a side note, but I was reading this article and it said
>
> > For a client needing to run 800 virtual instances, the annual cost of 
> >     a private cloud came to below $400,000 vs. somewhere between $800,000 
> >     and $1.2 million for public cloud services.

The 'free tier' gives you a t2.micro sized instance (1 vCPU, 1 GiB RAM) which you could leave turned on permanently for free during that free year.

Even after your free tier expires, that same instance would cost you $9.67/mth, and you have the option to go downgrade to a t2.nano (0.5 GiB RAM) which would only cost ~$4/mth - but 0.5GiB RAM isn't much these days, so may not be enough for you.

A t2.micro should be more than enough to learn how to build websites on.  If you are fortunate enough to build a site that is popular enough that you are getting more requests than that server can handle, then you will have to decide if you can generate revenue from that popularity sufficient to cover the cost, but by then you'll have more of a sense of how efficient your program is, and what instance size (and/or how many instances) you'll need.

> Yes, it's obviously a big company, but can you imagine "hitting the 
>   lottery" with an app everyone loves then before you know it, AWS hits 
>   you with a bill of $1,000,000

AWS protects you from yourself here a bit - they have [limits](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2) which generally restrict you from running more than 20 instances at a time - unless you ask for permission.  So, by default, your instance won't go multiplying like rabbits on it's own - unless you set it up to.  And even if you have set it up to, it won't be able to grow beyond 20 instances unless you have asked amazon to let you.  So, worst case is 20 x $9.67/mth - $197/mth.

But - that's just the instance cost.  Amazon charges you for lots of things including data traffic in and out, RDS instance costs, and if you start using other service such as S3 buckets and/or elastic load balancers, they all attract their own costs.

But hopefully, if you hit the lottery with an app everyone loves, you've worked out how to convert that love into dollars and cents so you can pay for all those instances you're going to need :)

Comment: Great explanation @Chris Simon. I think I have a better grasp on this. Correct me if I'm wrong, but can I say an "instance" is a "virtual machine" that runs an OS? Then obviously depending on how much load the "virtual machine" takes on with my website running determines if I want to cast a new "instances", hence design the programs efficiently.

Comment: The thing that confused me was all this talk of an "instance" being an "object". I'm also now learning some javascript and I think I had already reserved my definition of "object" and was trying to understand how the two were related, which maybe they are or aren't, but the explanation here helped provide some clarity.

Comment: That's right - the more load you put on the virtual machine (aka instance) the more instances you will need - or the bigger your instance will need to be.  The more efficient your program the more load it can handle for the same size/qty of instances.  However, I'd advise focusing on functionality first, and optimising for performance later, as you can get stuck making something super fast that doesn't actually do the right thing :)

Comment: Yep - 'instance' means very different things in AWS EC2 land to what it does in programming languages like javascript - but they are analogous - like if you have a cookie cutter (a 'class' in programming, or an AMI in AWS) you can stamp it out multiple times into multiple cookies - each is an 'instance' of the cookie cutter (aka instances of your class in code, or virtual machine instances from an AMI in AWS).  This analogy, like most, is not 100% perfect, but hopefully gives the gist of it.